# login page using session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I've created a login environment using jsp. `index.jsp, login.jsp`. I take username and password from database. If user name and password matches with the database it does login process perfectly. When user give wrong name or password it shows a error message `invalid name or password`and redirect to the login page. Nothing's wrong, but I am facing a problem when I login first. The place where the error message is shown after submitting wrong name or password that place is showing **null**.

Why null is showing?

Below is my code

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form  action="login.jsp" method="post">
        <center>
        <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" align ="left">Login Here</th>  <h5><%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%> </h5>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </center>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
 String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
 String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from member where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
    response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
} else {

    request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);


 }
%>
```

Comment: Is `null` displayed when you load index page or when you submit of login?

Comment: when i load index page

Comment: `errorMessage` attribute is null in the request when you load it first time, so you are getting null. You need to do null check for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your index.jsp

```
<% if ((String) request.getAttribute("errorMessage") != null) {%>
            <h3 style="color: red;"><%=(String) request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%></h3>
            <%
                }
            %>
```

Instead of this

```
<%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `errorMessage` attribute will not be available in request for the first time. Kindly check for a null and then display the message.

```
<%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%>
```

The below piece of code could help you.

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" align ="left">Login Here</th>
    <h5>
        <%
        String errorMsg = request.getAttribute("errorMessage");
        if (errorMsg != null) {
        %>
            <%=errorMsg%> 
        <%
        }
        %>
    </h5>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check condition before showing error, if request parameter is null then it should not be rendered else it would be rendered, modify you code according to below snippet

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align ="left">Login Here</th>  
        <h5>
          <%if(request.getParameter("errorMessage")!=null){%>
          <%=request.getParameter("errorMessage")%><%}%>
        </h5>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

As errorMessage attribute is null in the request when you load it first time, so you are getting null. You need to add **null check** for it. You can do this way

```
<th colspan="2" align ="left">Login Here</th>
<% if (request.getAttribute("errorMessage") != null) {
        out.println("<h5>" + request.getAttribute("errorMessage") + "</h5>");
}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code in login.jsp

write session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");

instead of request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");

..

null message show because of this.